# Admob + Android WebView issues

Tags: android, webview, admob, adview

I am a beginner in Android and I am trying to display ads on webview but I am getting an issue in my layout file "The following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView". I followed all the steps involved with using google play services. your help is much appreciated.

> MainActivity.Java

```
package com.test.webviewcode;


import com.test.webviewcode.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private AdView adView;
    private WebView mWebView;   
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.com/");
        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient1());


            // Create an ad.
            adView = new AdView(this);
            adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
            adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);
            LinearLayout Layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            Layout.addView(adView);
            AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
            .addTestDevice("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy")
            .build();
            adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){        
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
      @Override
      public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.resume();
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onPause() {
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.pause();
        }
        super.onPause();
      }

      /** Called before the activity is destroyed. */
      @Override
      public void onDestroy() {
        // Destroy the AdView.
        if (adView != null) {
          adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
      }
}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" >
      <!-- 
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
        ads:refreshInterval="30" >
        -->
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >


       <ProgressBar
           android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:progress="50"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/greenprogress" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Mainfest File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.webviewcode"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
                <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
               android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: i think u r using banner adv of admob

Comment: Naveen, Could you please elaborate and tell me how I can fix the issue

Comment: .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
.addTestDevice("yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy")  Remove this two line from your code and no problem in your i think adv is loading please back your screen i think u r geting adv

Comment: webview still crashes. I still have the error: "The following classes could not be instantiated: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView"

Comment: Give Mail id i will send u code i

Comment: @tattva Which version of the google play services library are you using. Check the manifest for the version code. Also, make sure you don't have the old admob sdk jar in your libs folder. Do a project > clean too

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have not included the Google Play Services library in your APK.

Note that you also have some other fundamental problems with your code.

1. You are creating your AdView in both code and in XML. Don't do that. Create it once only. I'd suggest in XML. And then use findViewById to get a reference to it.
2. You have 2 items in your XML with an id of adView. That will never work. Give the LinearLayout a different id.